# How to get the post title or id from a custom plugin in the admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, carrington

I am using `Carrington Build` theme and I've created a custom module.

Now, I need to check in which pages these modules are being using and generate a list somewhere else.

To achieve this I am trying to get the current page in which the module has been added from the admin side page. but everytime I open the module admin panel in the page it never returns the existing page with the following wp commands.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to get the current page from the admin side?

I've tried `get_the_ID()`, `wp_title()`, `single_post_title()`